# Modular arithmetic

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Given $e,d,N$ such that $e \times d \equiv 1 \pmod{ \varphi(n)}$. Can we efficiently calculate  $\varphi(N)$.

$\varphi(N)$ will have multiples values. We need to eliminate those values that are

1. higher than $N$
2. Odd 
   and some other criteria

Is there any efficient algorithm to find  $\varphi(N)$.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747013/how-to-factor-rsa-modulus-given-the-public-and-private-exponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow algorithm is able to factor $n$  with probability at least $\frac{1}{2}$:

> RSA-FACTOR(n, a, b)
>
> comment: we are assuming that $ab=1\pmod {\phi(n)}$
>
> write $ab - 1 = 2^sr$
>
> choose $w$ at random such that $1\leq w \leq n-1$
>
> $x= gcd(w, n)$
>
> if $l<x<n$ then return $(x)$
>
> comment: $x$ is a factor of $n$
>
> $v=w^r \pmod n$
>
> if $v=1 \pmod n$ then
>
> then return ("failure")
>
> while $v \ne  1 \pmod n$ do
>
> $v_0=v$
>
> $v =v^2 \pmod n$
>
> if $v_0=-1 \pmod n$ then return ("failure")
>
> else $x=gcd (v_0+ 1 , n )$
>
> return $(x)$

This is an algorithm 5.10 in the page $204$ of "CRYPTOGRAPHY
THEORY AND PRACTICE" by DOUGLAS R. STINSON.

Comment: Does that algorithm also work when $ab\equiv 1 \pmod {\lambda(n)}$, since $ab\equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi(n)}$ is not a necessary condition for RSA to work?

Comment: Dear @CodesInChaos, In the proof of algorithm, $w^{2^sr}=1 \pmod n$ is important for us. So algorithm also work when $ab\equiv 1 \pmod {\lambda(n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

When you know $e,d,N$, you can calculate $ed-1$, which is a multiple of $\Phi(n)$. I guess that's what you meant by

> $\Phi(n)$ will have multiple values.

The sentence itself is wrong, though. As a function it does not have "multiple values" for a fixed $n$. You know *a multiple of the value*.

There are various algorithms to do this:

- A probabilistic algorithm was given in the original RSA paper [A method for obtaining digital signatures and public-key cryptosystems](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359342) by Rivest, Shamir and Adleman, 1978
- A deterministic algorithm was given in [Computing the RSA Secret Key is Deterministic Polynomial Time Equivalent to Factoring](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520213/det.pdf) by May, 2004.
- [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5747441) references a different paper called *Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem* by Boneh, 1999.

This looks like a homework question, so I won't give an explicit algorithm.